# Bei XY unterm Sofa?

Tags: expression, phrase, colloquial

Ich hatte in mein Notizbuch diesen Ausdruck geschrieben:

> "Wie bei Heini Geiger unterm Sofa" (*C'est le bazar!*, *Es ist sehr unordentlich*)

Es scheint unmöglich zu sein, mithilfe von Google mehr über Heini Geiger zu erfahren.

Ich habe nur dieses im Leo-Wörterbuch gefunden:

> Da sieht es aus wie bei Hempels unterm Sofa" ("Dort ist es sehr unordentlich")

Aber kommt jetzt eine andere Frage: Wer ist Hempels? Eine Familie?

Kann mir das jemand erklären?

Comment: Ich habe beides noch nie gehört. Allerdings kann ich sagen, dass Hempel vermutlich ein Familienname ist.

Comment: Notenheft soll wohl ein Notizbuch sein.

Comment: @thei: richtig. Ich hatte "carnet de note" direkt übersetzt.

Comment: Die Hempels sind mir geläufig, der Heini Geiger nicht. @thei.

Comment: Heini Geiger habe ich auch nie gehört, weder in Moselfranken, noch München oder Berlin.

Comment: +1 Coole Frage. Hempels ist mir geläufig, aber nur ohne Hintergrund. Den Heini habe ich noch nie gehört.

Comment: Da sich hier alle einig sind, dass *Hempels* weitaus geläufiger ist als *Heini Geiger*, vermute ich, dass hier jemand eine alte Redewendung aufmotzen wollte. So ähnlich wie im Fall von *Der macht sich zum Affen*, wo sich irgendwann in der Jugendsprache die Abwandlung *Der macht sich um Obst* durchsetzte. (Ich glaube allerdings nicht, dass sich Heini Geiger so bald gegen die guten alten Hempels durchsetzen wird.)

Answer (score 13):

Also bei mir daheim (= Sachsen) heißt es definitiv "Hempels" und ist sehr verbreitet. Von "Heini Geiger" habe ich hingegen noch nie gehört. Das könnte regional aber auch sicher verschieden sein.

Eine Erklärung habe ich [hier](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme143/article942711.html) gefunden:

> Wie bei Hempels unterm Wohnwagen!
>
> Der Spruch lautete zuerst [so]. Das Sofa ist eine Umbildung, nachdem man die ursprüngliche Herkunft des Spruches vergessen hatte.
>
> "Bei euch sieht's aus wie bei Hempels unterm Wohnwagen: Bei euch herrscht ein heilloses Durcheinander und eine große Unsauberkeit. -- Der Autor* verdankt die Entstehungsgeschichte dieser Wendung Lorenz Hagenbeck, dem Sohn Carl Hagenbecks (1844-1913), der den Tierpark Stellingen bei Hamburg gründete: »Wie Sie wissen, haben die Artisten in aller Welt eine besonders hohe Meinung von Moral, Ordnung und Sauberkeit. Überall, wo wir mit unserem Zirkus erschienen, fanden wir daher vorbildliche Verhältnisse einer Gemeinschaft von Varieté- und Zirkuskünstlern, von Schaustellern und anderen Vertretern des fahrenden Volks. Nur einmal tanzte um die Jahrhundertwende in einer süddeutschen Stadt ein Budenbesitzer namens Hempel aus der Reihe, der regelmäßig Müll und andere Abfälle unter seinen Wohnwagen anstatt in die vorgesehenen Behälter kehrte. Es gelang uns schnell, die Ordnung wiederherzustellen und ihn nach vergeblichen Ermahnungen mit Hilfe der  Stadtverwaltung des Geländes zu verweisen. Was von ihm übrigblieb, war ein dunkler Fleck auf dem Rummelplatz und die Redensart: Bei euch sieht's ja aus, wie bei Hempels unterm Wohnwagen!"

...ob das stimmt, weiß ich leider nicht, aber es wird auch [hier](http://www.wlz-fz.de/Lokales/Serien/Redewendungen/Wie-bei-Hempels-unterm-Sofa) bestätigt.

Comment: +1. Wenn das stimmt, ist es eine hübsche Geschichte.

Answer (score 7):

Eine nicht minder plausible Erklärung für die Redewendung *"wie bei Hempels unterm Sofa"* findet man bei [GEOlino](http://www.geo.de/GEOlino/mensch/redewendungen/deutsch/58672.html):

> Fest steht, dass "Hempel" sich aus dem Wort "Hampel" herleitet, womit man früher einen einfältigen und unkultivierten Menschen bezeichnete. Dieser Begriff war schon zu Zeiten Martin Luthers (1483-1546) bekannt. Erst im 20. Jahrhundert verbreitete sich dann die Redewendung von "Hempels Sofa".

Ähnlich wird es auch im [Redensarten.net](http://www.redensarten.net/Hempels.html) hergeleitet:

> Redensart neueren und unbekannten Ursprungs, auch wenn schon Luther **grober Hempel** als Synonym für einen unkultivierten Menschen verwendet. Im übrigen leitet sich von Hempel auch der allseits bekannte Hampelmann her.

Comment: +1 die Hampelmannversion finde ich ziemlich glaubwürdig.

Comment: Interessant,.ich dachte immer, Hampelmann kommt von hampeln. Dann ist es wohl eher umgekehrt.